# Search for an user name in file and output the user's phone number

Tags: scripting

First I made a file called *telephone* containing:

```
Jan;032569874    
Annemie;014588529    
Hans;015253694    
Stefaan;011802367
```

And what I now need to do is make a script where the user inputs a name and the output should look like,

```
The phone number of Jan is 032569874
```

I tried a lot of things but nothing worked like its supposed to do. I know its a very easy one but I just can't get it.

Ok guys those answers are clearly from a higher level. This is what I got:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Solution script2

IFS=";"

echo "Whose phone number do you want to know?"
read name
read name number <$1
echo "The phone number of $name is $number."
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a roughly modified version of your script:

```
$ more cmd.bash 
#!/bin/bash

echo "Whose phone number do you want to know?"
read name
number=$(grep "$name" telephone | cut -d';' -f2)
echo ''
echo "The phone number of $name is $number."
```

It works as follows:

```
$ ./cmd.bash 
Whose phone number do you want to know?
Hans

The phone number of Hans is 015253694.
```

#### How it works

It simply takes in the name via the `read name` command and stores what was typed in the variable, `$name`. We then grep through the file `telephone` and then use `cut` to split the resulting line from the file `telephone` into 2 fields, using the semicolon as the separation character. The phone number, filed 2, is stored in the variable `$number`.

#### Testing

You can use the following script to test that your script works, using the data from the file `telephone`.

```
$ while read -r i ;do 
    echo "-----"
    echo "Test \"$i\""
    ./cmd.bash <<<$i
    echo "-----"
  done < <(cut -d';' -f1 telephone)
```

The above commands read in the contents of the file `telephone`, split it on the semicolon, `;`, and then takes each value from field 1 (then names) and loops through them 1 at a time. Each name is then passed to your script, `cmd.bash`, via STDIN, aka. `<<<$i`. This simulates a user typing in each of the names.

```
$ while read -r i ;do echo "-----"; echo "Test \"$i\""; \
    ./cmd.bash <<<$i; echo "-----"; done < <(cut -d';' -f1 telephone)
-----
Test "Jan"
Whose phone number do you want to know?

The phone number of Jan is 032569874.
-----
-----
Test "Annemie"
Whose phone number do you want to know?

The phone number of Annemie is 014588529.
-----
-----
Test "Hans"
Whose phone number do you want to know?

The phone number of Hans is 015253694.
-----
-----
Test "Stefaan"
Whose phone number do you want to know?

The phone number of Stefaan is 011802367.
-----
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { FS=";" } $1 ~ name { print "The number of " name " is " $2 }
```

```
phones -v name=Jan telephone                                      
The number of Jan is 032569874
```

Answer (score 2):

```
name="jan"
line="$(grep -i ^"$name" file)"
if [ -n "$line" ]; then
  number="${line#*;}"
  echo "The phone number of ${name} is ${number}"
else
  echo "There is no phone number for ${name}."
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `grep` command with `\k` notify and [lookbehind assertion](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```bsh
$ read name; echo "The phone number of $name is $(grep -oP "$name;\K.*" telephone)"
  Jan                                  #Input
  The phone number of Jan is 032569874 #Output
```

grep with `-P`(perl-regexp) parameter supports `\K`, which use to ignoring the previously matched characters(ignore name and semicolon;).

`-o, --only-matching`: print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line.

`$(command)` "Command Substitution" that allows the output of a command to replace the command name.

Or you can use the lookbehind assertion in place of nifty `\K`.

```bsh
$ read name; echo "The phone number of $name is $(grep -oP "(?<=$name;).*" telephone)"
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple one-liner:

```
read name; grep $name telephone | awk -F ';' '{print "The phone number of "$1" is "$2}'
```

Example usage:

```
Jan
The phone number of Jan is 032569874
```

- `read` reads the input into a variable called `name`. The input is accepted after `read` receives a newline or carriage return (e.g. pressing Enter).
- `grep` searches the telephone file for the input stored in `name`, returning a single line assuming the name only occurs once.
- `awk` is asked to use a semicolon (;) as the field delimiter via the `-F ';'` parameter. The semicolon is in quotes to prevent the shell from interpreting it.
- The `awk` program `{print "The phone number of "$1" is "$2}` prints the desired text while substituting `$1` and `$2` with their respective fields obtained from the line piped in from `grep`.

You can store this line in your `.sh` file and run it as a script.

Comment: `awk` does pattern matching, so the `grep` is redundant (and the pipe an overhead)...

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's|.*|s/\\(&\\);\\([0-9]*\\).*/\\1'\''s phone # is \\2./p|;q' </dev/tty|
sed -nf - /dev/fd/3 3<<\IN
Jan;032569874 
Annemie;014588529 
Hans;015253694 
Stefaan;011802367
IN
```

The first `sed` reads a line of input from the terminal and converts it to a working `s///` substitution statement for the second `sed`. There's nothing fancy here - as is it will break if you give it `/` on input for example, but, basically, it works:

#### OUTPUT

```
#I typed the line below then ENTER
Annemie
Annemie's phone # is 014588529.
```

You'll probably want to do `sed -nf - phonefilename` rather than the `/dev/fd/3` I used for the filename to demonstrate. And in that case you won't need the `<<IN...IN` heredoc bit.